# Help I am face the Error: Compile Error: Expression cannot be assigned at line -1 column -1 when save the trigger

Tags: apex

```
trigger CreateTaskWhenNewLeadGenerate on Lead (after insert) {

  Set<Id> LdIdSet = new Set<Id>();

     for ( Lead Ld : Trigger.New ){

         if ( Ld.Id != null ){
             LdIdSet.add ( Ld.Id );
         }

    } 



    List<Lead> LdList = [ SELECT Id,Name,OwnerId,Company,Email, Phone,pi__comments__c,Leasing_agent__c,Lead_Property_Of_Interest__c FROM Lead WHERE Id IN : LdIdSet];

    System.debug('*********LdList**********'+LdList);
    System.debug('*********LdList.Size()**********'+LdList.size());


    Map<Id,List<Lead>> LIdLdListMap = new Map<Id,List<Lead>>();
    List<Task> insTskList;
    List<Lead> updLdList;

        // Starts Of Outter IF
    if ( LdList.size() > 0 ){

        Datetime myDateTime;
        Date taskActivityDate;
        String dayOfWeek;

        myDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(Date.today().addDays(5), Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0));
        dayOfWeek = myDateTime.format('EEEE');

        if ( dayOfWeek.equals('Saturday') ){
            // set task due date(Activity Date) to next Monday date from current date as this day of week is Staturday
            taskActivityDate = Date.today().addDays(7);
        }else if ( dayOfWeek.equals('Sunday') ){
            // set task due date(Activity Date) to next Monday date from current date as this day of week is Sunday
            taskActivityDate = Date.today().addDays(6);    
        }else{                 
            // set task due date(Activity Date) to next Fifth day from current date
            taskActivityDate = Date.today().addDays(5);
        }

        insTskList = new List<Task>();
        updLdList = new List<Lead>();
        Task newTskObj;

        List<Lead> LList = new List<Lead>();
        Id LId = LdList.get( 0 ).Leasing_agent__c;

        for ( Lead L : LdList ){

            if ( LId == L.Leasing_agent__c ){        
                LList.add ( L );        
            }else{       
                LIdLdListMap.put ( LId , LdList ); 
                LdList = new List<Lead>();
                LdList.add ( L ); 
                LId = L.Leasing_agent__c;  
            }            

        }

        if ( LList.size() > 0 && LId != null )
           LIdLdListMap.put (LId, LList );  

        // Starts Of Trigger.New For Loop  
        for ( Leasing_agent__c agent : Trigger.New ){

            // Starts of Active / Inactive IF
            if ( Trigger.OldMap.get ( agent.Id ).IS_ACTIVE__C &&  ! agent.IS_ACTIVE__C ){            

                    LdList = LIdLdListMap.get(agent.Id) ;    

                if ( LList == null || LList.size() == 0 )
                    continue;

                // Starts Of Lead Inner For Loop  
                for ( Lead Ld : LList ){

                    // If there is no Lead property of interest on the Lead, check Property field in the Amendment/Lease Information section.                     
                  if ( Ld.Lead_Property_Of_Interest__c == null ){

                         // If there is a Property then  update the Lead with the new Leasing agent assigned to the Property.  
                         // If there Property agent = Null, then assign task to prospect coordinator.
                        if ( Ld.Lead_Property_Of_Interest__c == BP_Property__c.Name){
                           system.debug('Check the is_active field');
                             BP_Property__c.Name = ' ';
                             updLdList.add ( Ld );

                         }else{ 

                             newTskObj = new Task();
                             newTskObj.Subject = 'PC-Leasing Call';                                                               
                             newTskObj.OwnerId = Ld.OwnerId; 
                             newTskObj.WhatId = Ld.Id;
                             newTskObj.ActivityDate = taskActivityDate;
                             insTskList.add ( newTskObj );

                         }
                    // If the Lead has Lead Property of Interest and there is a new primary agent assign to the property: update the Lead with the new Leasing agent.                    
                    }else if ( Ld.Lead_Property_Of_Interest__c != null && Ld.Lead_Property_Of_Interest__r.Leasing_agent_Active_In_active__c ){
                                agent.IS_ACTIVE__c = true;
                                Ld.Leasing_agent__c = Ld.Lead_Property_Of_Interest__r.Leasing_agent__c ;                      
                                updOppList.add ( Ld );

                    // If the Lead has Lead Property of Interest but having In-Active agent then assign task to prospect coordinator.   
                    }else{

                         newTskObj = new Task();
                         newTskObj.Subject = 'LAInitial-Leasing Call';                                                                 
                         newTskObj.Description = 'The leasing agent of the Lead is inactive. Please assign the Lead with Prospect coordinator.';                                                                                                        
                         newTskObj.ActivityDate = taskActivityDate;                       
                         newTskObj.OwnerId = Ld.OwnerId; 
                         newTskObj.WhatId = Ld.Id;                         
                         insTskList.add ( newTskObj );

                     }                
                 }// Starts Of Lead Inner For Loop  

              }// End of Active / Inactive IF 

        }// End Of Trigger.New For Loop  

        if ( updLdList.size() > 0 )
            UPDATE updLdList;

        if ( insTskList.size() > 0 )
            INSERT insTskList;
          //System.debug('****Task insert****' );   

        Insert newTskObj ;  
    }// End Of Outter IF 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular error is on this line:

```
BP_Property__c.Name = ' ';
```

You're trying to assign a value to `BP_Property__c.Name`, which is aliased to `Schema.BP_Property__c.Name`, which is a read-only static variable that represents an `SObjectField` token.

Your entire trigger has at least one other error where you're using that `SObjectField` token incorrectly, and one error that will crash your trigger, because Trigger.oldMap will be null during insert, plus a number of optimization and bulkification problems.